# Errors when compiling LLVM's compiler-rt in ubuntu12.04

Tags: compilation, llvm

How can I compile compiler-rt of llvm (compiler-rt.llvm.org) in ubuntu12.04?

When I compile the compiler-rt, I get errors:

```
rong@rong-VirtualBox:~/source/compile-rt/build$ cmake ../compiler-rt/
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    LLVMParseArguments


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:21 (string):
  string sub-command REGEX, mode MATCH needs at least 5 arguments total to
  command.


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/AddCompilerRT.cmake:1 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    AddLLVM
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:36 (include)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/AddCompilerRT.cmake:2 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    LLVMParseArguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:36 (include)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/CompilerRTUtils.cmake:21 (string):
  string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:109 (find_flag_in_string)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:138 (check_cxx_compiler_flag):
  Unknown CMake command "check_cxx_compiler_flag".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
rong@rong-VirtualBox:~/source/compile-rt/build$
```

Comment: You should compile it from LLVM source tree.

Answer (score 2):

`compiler_rt` is meant to be compiled within the LLVM source tree. [This page](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) has detailed instructions on how to create this tree with llvm, clang and compiler-rt, compile and test everything. Should work like a charm on Ubunbu.

Pro tip: it's much faster to build the whole thing with CMake+Ninja. See [instructions here](http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html).

Comment: http://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/CF/CF-635.21.tar.gz  

oh thank you!i download this version CFLite,and it can be compiled now!i used a project called "blocksruntime-master" to compile the compiler-rt for install the Block.h

Answer (score 1):

I got compiler-rt compiled for i386 and x64 using

> make clang_linux

check the available platform using

```
make info-platforms
```